# Looking for value in List

Tags: java, list, collections

I have List declared as

```
        private List<Employees> employees;
```

and in I am getting values from database using DAO as

```
        employees= new ArrayList<Employees>();
        employees.addAll(myDAO.getEmployees());
```

I would like to search for a value in `employees List`, what is the best approach for looking for a value in `employees List`?

I have tried

```
    Collections.sort(employees);
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(employees, "abc");
```

However I am getting cast Exception

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `looking for a value`? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to search for "abc" (a String) in a list of Employee objects?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I have String called "abc", I would like to look for abc in `employees List`

Comment: Employee is not a String.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, you should always specify **at which exact code line** the exception occurs. And, if there is an exception message you should **specify the exception message**. This makes it much easier for people to help you, and thusly much more likely for you to receive appropriate help.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Hmm... You are right... But... Then it shouldn't be possible to get any exception should it? There should be a compilation error, and hence the it shouldn't even be possible to run the code, so no exception can be obtained, can it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(employees); // BigO - nlog(n)
int index = Collections.binarySearch(employees, new Employee("abc",...)); // BigO - log(n)
```

if you sort every time your list and search it, Code complexity would be `nlog(n) + log(n)` where `nlog(n)` for sorting list and `log(n)` for binary search.

It is better if you search your list linearly. liner search would take `BigO - n` which perform better than previous approach.

---

You are getting `cast Exception` in `Collections#sort` method because of your list contain `null value` which unable to cast Employee and raise `ClassCastException`

Comment: I have             `Collections.sort(employees);
           int index = Collections.binarySearch(employees, "abc");` When I compile I am getting `sort(java.util.List<test.Employees>) not found in class java.util.Collections`

Comment: `"abc"` you should pass `Employee Object`.`binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)`

Comment: @Polppan, does Employees implement the Comparable interface?

Answer (score 1):

```
Employees lookingForValue(String value, List<Employees> employees)
{
    for (Employees employee : employees)
    {
       if (value.equals(employee.getFieldValue()))
       {
          return employee;
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

usage

```
lookingForValue("abc", employees);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can´t use

```
myDAO.getEmployees(parameter);
```

and in your DAO **put a where clause**
then you can do a for and search for an object

```
Employee emp = null;

    for(Employee e : employees) {
       if(e.getName().equals("X"))
           emp = e;
    }

    if(emp != null) {
      //handle the found employee
    }
    else {
      //employee not in list
    }
```

Sure you can also override its equals method, instanciate an object with that column and use (I would not recommend it)

```
myDAO.getEmployees().get(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list and perform the search action:

```
String searchString = "abc";
for(Employee employee: employees) {
  if(employee.getName().equals(searchString)) {
    // Found something!
  }
}
```

If you want to search all fields of `Employee`, you might want to create a method in `Employee` that checks all fields on the instance:

```
boolean findString(String searchString) {
  if(getName().equals(searchString)) return true;
  if(getCity().equals(searchString)) return true;
  // etc..
  return false;
}
```

and use this method in your `for`-loop.

Comment: is this the best way to his problem?

Comment: 'best' is debatable, it is *a* solution to his problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is very large I suggest doing the search in the DAO - dbs can be tuned for best performance for this kind of search (eg `select * from employees where name = 'abc'`) then have a DAO method to return only the items that match.

Another nice alternative is apache-commons [Predicate](http://commons.apache.org/collections//apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html)

eg

```
matches = CollectionUtils.filter(employees, new Predicate<Employee>()
{
  @Override
  public boolean evaluate(Employee object)

    return "abc".equals(object.getName());
  }
});
```

Obviously, parameterize out the "abc". Make the Predicate a named class if you want to reuse it.

Predicate implementations are particularly useful if you have many different ways you want to filter the set; plus it leaves equals free for true equality checking.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer... +1. It may be possible to pass the search to the database avoiding searching the entire list.  However, this is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Simply override the equals method in Employees (shouldn't this be Employee? Does it describe a collection of employees or only one?)

Your code should then work.  You could also Sort your employees as above and provide a comparator:

```
Collections.sort(fields, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1,Employee o2) {
        // TODO Rerturn 0 if equal or either 1 or -1 depending which of o1 or o2 is the bigger
    }
})
```

In the latter approach you DO NOT need to override the equals method.